# I need to sum values with specific condition

Tags: mysql

I have table like this:

| Id | km | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 20-5-2020 |
| 1 | 9 | 20-5-2020 |
| 3 | 7 | 20-5-2020 |
| 1 | 4 | 10-5-2020 |
| 3 | 2 | 10_5_2020 |
| 4 | 9 | 10_5_2020 |

What i need is to sum the km for each id in the month, I want the result like this:

| Id | km 20 may | km 10 may |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 14 | 4 |
| 3 | 7 | 2 |
| 4 | 0 | 9 |

I tried this code and didn't get the result that I want

```
Select id, 
sum(select km from info where date =='10_5_2020') as 'km 10 may',
Sum(select km from unfo where date == '20-5-2020') as 'km 20 may'
From info
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression inside your sum to limit what you are summing:

```
SELECT id, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN date ='10_5_2020' THEN km ELSE 0 END) as 'km 10 may',
        SUM(CASE WHEN date = '20-5-2020' THEN km ELSE 0 END) as 'km 20 may'
From    info
GROUP BY id;
```

Also worth noting that if you are selecting `id` and doing an aggregate, then you also need to group by `id`

---

**ADENDUM**

To explain this in a bit more detail, consider what the case expression does without the `SUM`:

| Id | km | date | CASE WHEN date = '20-5-2020' THEN km ELSE 0 END | CASE WHEN date ='10_5_2020' THEN km ELSE 0 END |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 20-5-2020 | 5 | 0 |
| 1 | 9 | 20-5-2020 | 9 | 0 |
| 3 | 7 | 20-5-2020 | 7 | 0 |
| 1 | 4 | 10-5-2020 | 0 | 4 |
| 3 | 2 | 10_5_2020 | 0 | 2 |
| 4 | 9 | 10_5_2020 | 0 | 9 |

Now all your SUM is doing is summing the values in those derived columns. If you remove the `ELSE 0` then instead of `0` you'll get `NULL` in those columns:

| Id | km | date | CASE WHEN date = '20-5-2020' THEN km END | CASE WHEN date ='10_5_2020' THEN km END |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 20-5-2020 | 5 | NULL |
| 1 | 9 | 20-5-2020 | 9 | NULL |
| 3 | 7 | 20-5-2020 | 7 | NULL |
| 1 | 4 | 10-5-2020 | NULL | 4 |
| 3 | 2 | 10_5_2020 | NULL | 2 |
| 4 | 9 | 10_5_2020 | NULL | 9 |

Your SUM will still work, but instead of `0` in the output you'll get `NULL` if there are no matching values

Comment: Why should i wrote (else 0 ) here ? Because i tried this code without it and didn't work

Comment: What do you mean by *"didn't work"*? Did you get an error, did you get a different result?

Comment: may i ask you another question please ?

Comment: Yes, of course. But if it is a new question rather than asking for clarification on this one, then it would be best raised as [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), rather than via the comments